# React - How to return one of several components in the render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my state I have `showTab1`, `showTab2`, `showTab3`. If tab i is selected, then the other tabs are set to false. So in my `render` function I want to be able to return something like this:

```
  return (
    <div>
      {
        (() => {
          if (someCondition) {
            if (this.state.showTab1) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Tab1/>
                </div>
              )
            } else if (this.state.showTab2) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Tab2/>
                </div>
              )
            } else if (this.state.showTab3) {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Tab3/>
                </div>
              )
            }
          }

          return <span />;
        })()
      }

      <AnotherComponent>
    </div>
  );
```

But I know that it's not allowed to have multiple returns, or at least it's considered bad practice. How can I get around this?

Comment: "it's considered bad practice" - Never heard about that. It's pretty common to have at least 2 returns in the render function: `if (!data) return null; return (<div>...</div>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd use a single variable to determine which tab you need and then you could use a `switch` statement instead of multiple `if`s. Something like this would be nice:

```
render() {
    const { currentTabId } = this.props;
    let CurrentTab;
    switch( currentTabId ) {
        case 'tab1':
            CurrentTab = Tab1;
            break;
        case 'tab2':
            CurrentTab = Tab2;
            break;
        case 'tab3':
            CurrentTab = Tab3;
            break;
        default:
            CurrentTab = null;
    };
    return <div>{ CurrentTab && <CurrentTab /> }</div>;
}
```

or

```
render() {
    const { currentTabId } = this.props;
    const tabs = {
        tab1: Tab1,
        tab2: Tab2,
        tab3: Tab3,
    };
    const CurrentTab = tabs[ currentTabId ] || null;
    return <div>{ CurrentTab && <CurrentTab /> }</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do your tabs have in common, and what makes one different from the other ones?

Having that in mind create a single `Tab` component that takes the needed properties (differences) and renders accordingly. But ... why?

React is awesome because it can know the minimal amount of changes needed to the DOM in order to represent the state you've set, allowing you to handle your entire UI as a state-based system. The good performance of React is based on how well it can tell those differences.

If your `render` method returns an entirely different component each time, React will [remove one and append the other](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types) because it can't tell the difference between one and the other. But if you specify with properties and the state what changes and what doesn't change in your component, then it'll do its job very well. The DOM is awful, it has always been, the less changes you make to it, the better your page will behave.

Does that mean you can't return three entirely different components? Of course not, but if you would do that on all of your components, then you would have a very serious performance issue. That sounds pretty much like a bad practice and good enough reason to avoid it.

Take SO tabs at the right as a very trivial example, and supose you navigate to them from other place in the page, therefore only the one active is shown.

If you do this:

```
<div>
  {() => {
    if (this.state.active === 'jobs')
      return <Jobs>;
    if (this.state.active === 'doc')
      return <Documentation>;
    // ... you get it
  }}
</div>
```

Whenever you change `state.active` React will remove the tab, and append a new one.

But if you don't use a bad practice, and use a good practice like [stateless functional components](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.z3bb29om6)

```
const Tab = ({text, href, children}) => (
  <div>
    <a href={href}>{text}</a>
    {children}
  </div>
);

// In the parent one
textByTab() {
  switch(this.state.active) {
    case 'jobs':
      return 'Jobs';
    case 'doc':
      return 'Documentation';
  }
}

hrefByTab() { // ... you get it }

childrenByTab() {
  if (this.state.active === 'doc')
    return <span className="beta-thing">Beta</span>;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tab text={this.textByTab()} href={this.hrefByTab()}>
        {this.childrenByTab()}
      </Tab>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now React knows exactly what can change, how it can change, and can even [do fancy functional stuff](http://blog.agiledeveloper.com/2015/12/benefits-of-pure-functions.html) for even better performance.